# Why summing a generator takes more time than summing a list?

Tags: python-3.x, generator

I'm trying a code to sum the first one million numbers.

It's known that generators are more efficient and take less memory and time than lists, but the result of the code show the opposite.

Here's the code:

```
# sum the first million numbers
import time
start_time= time.time()
s=[x*x for x in range(1, 10000001)]
print (type(s))
s=sum(s)
end_time = time.time()
print(s)
print(end_time-start_time, " Seconds")

print("-"*50)

start_time= time.time()
s=(x*x for x in range(1, 10000001))
print (type(s))
s=sum(s)
end_time = time.time()
print(s)
print(end_time-start_time, " Seconds")
```

And here's the output:

```
> <class 'list'> 
> 333333383333335000000
> 1.3103523254394531  Seconds
> ________________
> 
> <class 'generator'> 
> 333333383333335000000
> 5.889586687088013  Seconds
```

Comment: Running the same code I got `1.1215989589691162  Seconds` and `0.9689059257507324  Seconds`. Seems like maybe you have other things running on your machine that ate time? Repeated runs might help elucidate what's going on.

Comment: I also got a marginally quicker result with the generator

Comment: It's seems you're right. I tried it on another environment and got results similar to yours, but still the delay should happen proportionally to both results regardless of the environment (generators should always work faster).